# BigQuery subquery for a SELECT MAX Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following query I want to run in BigQuery,

```
SELECT t1.Phone, t1.isOptOut, t1.campaignId, t1.timestamp
FROM PhoneTable t1
WHERE t1.campaignId=1
AND t1.timestamp > (
      SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
      FROM PhoneTable t2
      WHERE t2.Phone = t1.Phone
      AND t2.isOptOut = TRUE
      AND t2.campaignId IS NULL
)
ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I just want to retrieve a record that has no other record overriding it (based on timestamp). I understand that BigQuery does not support subqueries referencing the columns of the outer query, and I have seen some examples here but I have no idea how to fix this query. If I change the WHERE in the subquery and add t2.phone = "+15556665555" it works, but I need it to be equal to the phone in the outer query.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an error? I'm not clear on what is going wrong or what you are trying to do.

Comment: you should provide example of your PhoneTable (at least some number of rows) and example of expected result. also check if your query is correct as it is not understood where `t1` comes from.